# Not Creating Tables in Hibernate JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am creating Spring (Version 4.0.6) , Hibernate(Version 4.3.6) CRUD application.

I tried giving both `<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>` and `<property name="generateDdl" value="true" />`. But the tables did not get created. 
    All entities has `@Entity` and `@Table(name)` annotation from `javax.persistence`.

Here comes my `applicationContext.xml`. http://textuploader.com/5pjw8

Here comes one of my Entity 
    http://textuploader.com/5pjyk

1. Where I have gone wrong and why it is not creating tables for me?
2. How do I troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Did you get any specific errors?if so, put them here

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have defined a datasource bean, i.e. an actual database to connect to, is this in another file?